# Run Parallel jobs power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hello  PowerShell  gurus

I made this script  to  get  the latest KB patch installed on  a  remote PC.  And its now working. AL though  its crude and  something I just put together (while learning PS). It gets the job done… Painfully slow but  works. It takes over  2:40 hrs  to run  and check  128 PCs. I saw in other posts  that creating parallels jobs for this might  help. I have no idea  on how to create parallel jobs  please help me.

**my script**

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$(Get-location)\RESULTLOG-$(Get-date -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss").log"

Function Get-FileName{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$Importfile = Get-FileName
$Clients = Get-Content $Importfile

Foreach($Client in $Clients){

    #CHECK IF  PC IS ENABLED IN AD <<<<feature improvement 
    # if(get-adcomputer -Filter 'Name -like $p' -Properties Enabled)


    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Client -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        try { 
            Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Client -Description 'Security Update' | Select-Object -Last 1
        }
        catch { 
            "$Client;An error occurred." 
        }  
    }
    else{
        "$Client;not on line "
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

I'm also  trying to  work on  checking if PC  is  enabled  in  Active Directory  before  running the rest of the code, but I have that commented out for the mean time  what I got  works.

Can the performance  in this  be improved?? I know that network  speed  might have something to do   but for the amount of data  from each PC  should  not  take this long

Comment: `Invoke-command comp1,comp2,comp3 { 'whatever' }` runs in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "-Parallel" switch of ForEach-Object:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

You may need to change your code a bit in order to make it to work with the ForEach-Object call instead of the foreach block:

```
...
$Clients | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        try { 
            Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Description 'Security Update' | 
                Select-Object -Last 1
        }
        catch { 
            "$_;An error occurred." 
        }  
     }
     else {
        "$_;not on line "
     }
} -Parallel
...
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @doug-maurer in the comments as well as in the link I provided, this will only work on PowerShell v7-Preview-3 onwards.

Comment: Thanks   I will definitely look in to that read. On  a second note … I don't know how to phrase this question   is regarding the future  change I'm planing, the test evaluation  `if(get-adcomputer -Filter 'Name -like $_' -Properties Enabled)`  would this  return a simple true  or would it return a whole object ?  If so how can I get only the ENABLED  part out of that eval.?

Comment: The Get-AdComputer will return the entire object. What happens in your "if" statement is that it just checks if the return of that function is not null. I believe you should post this as a separate question, so I can try to elaborate a better answer.

Comment: OP tagged powershell 3.0. Workflows were introduced in 4 and that’s the first time -Parallel was available. Not available outside workflows until powershell core.

Comment: @Fabricio thanks  I will Post  as a separate question once I'm  finish  with  this    Parallel  issue

Comment: Fabricio  I have  upgraded to  PS 7.01,  and was able  to run the script however i notice when i put  over 200 PC's in the list the script will not complete and it will keep working for hours until it times out and does not finish.  But if I use the same script  with only  10 or 20 PC's on the list  the script  will complete successfully. i have tried using the `-TimeoutSeconds`  and  ` -ThrottleLimit `   buts still have  the same issue with large quantyties. any  sugestion ?

Comment: @victorR, the default parallelism is 5 (ThrottleLimit param). It means that only 5 script blocks will execute in parallel. I won't suggest you to increase this number, as it is limited to the number of parallel threads the calling system is able to handle. My suggestion is to use a different approach, maybe triggering these calls as Jobs on the remote computers, and have the results published somewhere in the network.